# Tracking universal analytics events through Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, tag-manager

I have an Universal Analytics property installed on my site through Google Tag Manager.

Following [this article](http://moz.com/ugc/tracking-google-analytics-events-with-google-tag-manager) on tracking classic *ga.js* events through GTM I have given my tracker a global name `_gua`. Now I try to fire events using additional HTML tag as described in the article:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { 
    $('.some-class').click(function () { 
        gua('send', 'event', 'button', 'click');
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The script is working fine but each time I call the `_gua` to send the event I get the following message from the [GA Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna):

```
Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
```

Is it even possible to use GTM and GUA this way? I don't want to use the data layer and GTM events...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've figured it out:

With GTM you have to create tags within the tool to handle and match with updates on the dataLayer object via `dataLayer.push("event", ...)` on your page, which then again "redirects" your events over the tags to Analytics.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#datalayer

For the `ga()` function, you need to set up a tracker first and use the direct Analytics tracking code (not GTM) for proper event tracking. See following links:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-analytics-analyticsjs/mayu2cf1d0k/UBkWsZEQvjYJ

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced

Personally I took the second, direct approach.